# Are Mermaid graphics supported in .rst (ReStructuredText) files on GitHub?

Tags: github, graph, restructuredtext, mermaid

GitHub announced that they included diagrams in Markdown files with Mermaid https://github.blog/2022-02-14-include-diagrams-markdown-files-mermaid/

I tried on a **.md** file and it works perfectly, I tried on a **.rst** file and it doesn't work. The graph is not rendered as in .md files. Are Mermaid graphics compatible with .rst files?

What I tried in a .rst was:

```
.. mermaid::

   flowchart LR
      A(PR arrives)-->B[Selective Check]
```

Comment: I doubt this works. GitHub _strongly_ promotes the use of Markdown over other markup formats. I'm not even able to find references to ReST or org-mode support in their official documentation at the moment. Given that this is a brand new feature, it's highly unlikely that it has already been rolled out to other supported formats. Furthermore... you have just tested it and found that it does not work.